# Turning MySQL queries into SQL Server queries

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I was given the task of building a database and the queries to interact with it. 
They did not tell me what kind of database to use, so I chose the one I know: MySQL

Now It seems that the database has to be a SQL Server one and dead line for this task is within hours :(

I have already converted the database from MySQL to SQL Serverusing a program called DBConvert.

But now I have to change all my queries and I have no idea about SQL Server. 
Is there any program/web that can do the magic, that can turn MySQL queties into SQL Serverones?

I'm learning about the SQL Serverenvironment so I'm installing the NET Framework and SQL Server 2005 Express, is that correct?

I'm looking for something like phpMyAdmin in SQL Server, is it SQL Server 2005 Express?

Sorry for all of this questioning, but as I said it is a matter of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the SQL Server 2005 Express is the MYSQL server and not like phpMyAdmin. For phpmyAdmin of SQL Server you can use MSSQL query analyzer (if you install MSSQL whole package this will be installed)

And I dont think so there is any program which will convert MYSQL queries to MSSQL queries.